# Error enabling Flyspell mode: Can't open ISO-8859-1

Tags: flyspell, ispell, hunspell

I have downloaded the hunspell build nto `~/lib/hunspell` on my windows machine.

I have included these lines in my `.emacs.d` config

```
  (setq tian/hunspell-directory (concat (expand-file-name "~/") "lib/hunspell/"))

  (setq ispell-program-name (concat tian/hunspell-directory "bin/hunspell.exe"))

  (setq tian/hunspell-dict-directory (concat
  tian/hunspell-directory
  "share/hunspell"))

  (setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
        '(
          (nil
           "[[:alpha:]]"
           "[^[:alpha:]]"
           "[']"
           t
           ("-d" "en_GB" "-p" )
          nil
          iso-8859-1)
        ))
```

When I run `flyspell-mode` in an `.org` file, I get the following error

```
Error enabling Flyspell mode:
(Can't open ISO-8859-1.)
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Try `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and see if the backtrace has more information. I suspect that it won't (there is a `condition-case` in `flyspell-mode` that catches errors) but it's worth trying nevertheless - and worth remembering for the future.

Comment: Are you able to run `hunspell` from the terminal -- without using Emacs -- such that you know for sure that the `hunspell` installation is working correctly?